# VueJS : Scroll to line of a table on load

Tags: vue.js, scroll, element, ref

I have a table (from the element framework), with a list of questions inside. I can choose one to modify, do my stuff, and once I validate, I'd like the page to scroll to the modified question.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <el-table :data="list">
            <el-table-column :label="$t('label')" width="300">
                <template slot-scope="scope">
                    <span :ref="list[scope.$index].id">{{ list[scope.$index].label }}</span>
                </template>
            </el-table-column>
```

Here's how I manage the ref of each question so it's unique

and in my `<script>` part :
`document.getElementById(this.$route.params.questionId).scrollIntoView();`

I send the id as a parameter in my url and get it in my list page just fine.
But with

```
console.log("Id : ", this.$route.params.questionId, this.$refs[this.$route.params.questionId])
document.getElementById(this.$route.params.questionId).scrollIntoView();
```

The questionId is fine, but the rest is undefined.

If I try to log `this.refs`, I get stuff [like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeNOB.png)

How can I get it to work ?

---

**Solutions I tried :**

- Adding : `this.$refs[this.$route.params.questionId].scrollIntoView()` into the `mounted` section.  , I get  `TypeError: "_this.$refs[_this.$route.params.questionId] is undefined"`
- Adding a questionId manually like `this.$refs(questionId).scrollIntoView()`, same error
- Doing a console.log of `this.$route.params.questionId` and `this.$refs` , I do get the questionId and the [refs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeNOB.png)
- Tried (still in mounted) :

```
this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.$refs[this.$route.params.questionId].scrollIntoView()
});
```

still undefined

---

Edit : Added log screenshot

Comment: Also, if I try `console.log(this.$refs)`, I do seem to get the list with all the informations, I just don't know how to access it

Comment: Can you share some samples of that output (`this.$refs`).

Comment: @User28 added the picture in edit, this is only for one question

Comment: Then you should do something like `this.$refs[this.$route.params.questionId].scrollIntoView()`.

Comment: I added this line into my `mounted` part, I now have this error :
`Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: "_this.$refs[_this.$route.params.questionId] is undefined"`

Comment: The problem seems to be the "mounted" part, as the scrolling does work if I set it as action for a button. Tried with a nextTick() in mounted, didn't work, I'll post the solution once I find out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was.

I was trying to do it in the **`mounted`** section, it seems like the page wasn't rendered and therefore `this.$refs[this.$route.params.questionId].scrollIntoView()` couldn't work (thus the **`undefined`** results I got)

Solution :

In the `<script>` part, I added

```
updated() {
    if(this.scrollOnLoad && this.$route.params.questionId){
        this.scroll();
        this.scrollOnLoad = false;
    }
},
```

which happens once the mounted part is over, as show on this [page](https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-lifecycle/).

---

### WARNING

**`Update`** will activate whenever you do an action, for example clicking in a TextInput (as in my case). I fixed this by using a boolean in the `data` section (updated the code above to match the solution)